# pandas convert the unique column value as a column name and place all relating Server names under it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below code where I want Server names to be put placed under as per `ENC1001` and `ENC1002`

These are Just two `ENC1001` & `ENC1002` but I have hundreds in real.

### Pandas code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C7000_Report_Servers_Report.xlsx",  sheet_name=0, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df = df[df['Enclosure Hardware'].str.contains('C7000')]
print(df)
```

### Output:

```
          Server Enclosure Hardware      Bay              Server Name
0        ENC1001              C7000    bay 1     dpcfl1001.example.com
1        ENC1001              C7000    bay 2     dpcfl1002.example.com
2        ENC1001              C7000    bay 3     dpcfl1003.example.com
3        ENC1001              C7000    bay 4     dpcfl1004.example.com
4        ENC1001              C7000    bay 5     dpcfl1005.example.com
5        ENC1001              C7000    bay 6     dpcfl1006.example.com
6        ENC1001              C7000    bay 7     dpcfl1007.example.com
7        ENC1001              C7000    bay 8     dpcfl1008.example.com
8        ENC1001              C7000    bay 9     dpcfl1009.example.com
9        ENC1001              C7000   bay 10     dpcfl1010.example.com
10       ENC1001              C7000   bay 11     dpcfl1011.example.com
11       ENC1001              C7000   bay 12                   inc1001
12       ENC1001              C7000   bay 13                   inc1003
13       ENC1001              C7000   bay 14     dpcfl2313.example.com
14       ENC1001              C7000   bay 15                   lic1002
15       ENC1002              C7000    bay 1     dpcfl1012.example.com
16       ENC1002              C7000    bay 2     dpcfl1013.example.com
17       ENC1002              C7000    bay 3     dpcfl1014.example.com
18       ENC1002              C7000    bay 4     dpcfl1015.example.com
19       ENC1002              C7000    bay 5     dpcfl1016.example.com
20       ENC1002              C7000    bay 6     dpcfl1017.example.com
21       ENC1002              C7000    bay 7     dpcfl1018.example.com
```

### What is desired:

```
ENC1001                             ENC1002                     
dpcfl1001.example.com               dpcfl1012.example.com       
dpcfl1002.example.com               dpcfl1013.example.com       
dpcfl1003.example.com               dpcfl1014.example.com       
dpcfl1004.example.com               dpcfl1015.example.com       
dpcfl1005.example.com               dpcfl1016.example.com       
dpcfl1006.example.com               dpcfl1017.example.com       
dpcfl1007.example.com               dpcfl1018.example.com       
dpcfl1008.example.com               None                           
dpcfl1009.example.com               None                           
dpcfl1010.example.com               None                        
dpcfl1011.example.com               None                            
              inc1001               None                            
              inc1003               None                        
dpcfl2313.example.com               None                            
              lic1002               None
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try: `df.pivot(columns="Server", values="Server Name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
pd.concat([g.set_index('Bay').add_suffix(f'_{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Server')], 
          axis=1, sort=False).filter(like='Server Name')
```

Output:

```
          Server Name_ENC1001    Server Name_ENC1002
bay 1   dpcfl1001.example.com  dpcfl1012.example.com
bay 2   dpcfl1002.example.com  dpcfl1013.example.com
bay 3   dpcfl1003.example.com  dpcfl1014.example.com
bay 4   dpcfl1004.example.com  dpcfl1015.example.com
bay 5   dpcfl1005.example.com  dpcfl1016.example.com
bay 6   dpcfl1006.example.com  dpcfl1017.example.com
bay 7   dpcfl1007.example.com  dpcfl1018.example.com
bay 8   dpcfl1008.example.com                    NaN
bay 9   dpcfl1009.example.com                    NaN
bay 10  dpcfl1010.example.com                    NaN
bay 11  dpcfl1011.example.com                    NaN
bay 12                inc1001                    NaN
bay 13                inc1003                    NaN
bay 14  dpcfl2313.example.com                    NaN
bay 15                lic1002                    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Scott +1, its nice another way around.

Comment: This is a best bet and best fitted as i see bay number as well.

Comment: @user294110 Thanks. Happy coding!

Comment: Can you please explain  `add_suffix(f'_{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Server')], axis=1, sort=False).filter(like='Server Name')` , sorry for asking too late.

Comment: You are adding a suffix to each column with the suffix being the Server, then you concat all thos groups side by side with 'axis=1' and lastly, you only selct the columns that start with 'Server Name' using filter.

Comment: @ScottBoston, Sir can you explain `pd.concat([g.set_index('Bay').add_suffix(f'_{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Server')], axis=1, sort=False).filter(like='Server Name')` , i am looking for similar but i don't need  Suffix rather i Need only like `ENC100` , ever thankful to you. I have raised [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67866824/pandas-to-format-the-csv-data-from-the-desired-columns) but did not get any concrete answer.

Comment: @krock1516 I think you need to reshape the dataframe differently.  Could you create a new question using these data if you like and show the shape of the output dataframe you wish to have?

Comment: @Scott Boston sir, I have raised the so post as I mentioned in my previous comment, and your Solution works perfectly only I don't need suffix like `ServerName_Enc1001`  and need `Enc1001` without suffix. Rest all works fine though. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @krock1516 Try:  `pd.concat([g.set_index('Bay')['Server Name'].rename(f'{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Server')], 
          axis=1, sort=False)`

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df.head(9))


Server Enclosure Hardware   Bay            Server Name
    0  ENC1001              C7000  bay1  dpcfl1001.example.com
    1  ENC1001              C7000  bay2  dpcfl1002.example.com
    2  ENC1001              C7000  bay3  dpcfl1003.example.com
    3  ENC1001              C7000  bay4  dpcfl1004.example.com
    4  ENC1001              C7000  bay5  dpcfl1005.example.com
    5  ENC1001              C7000  bay6  dpcfl1006.example.com
    6  ENC1001              C7000  bay7  dpcfl1007.example.com
    7  ENC1001              C7000  bay8  dpcfl1008.example.com
    8  ENC1001              C7000  bay9  dpcfl1009.example.com  

 

 

    df2=df.groupby(['Server','Enclosure Hardware','Bay'])['Server Name'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.tolist())).unstack('Server').fillna('None').reset_index().drop(columns=['level_2'])



Server Enclosure Hardware    Bay                ENC1001                ENC1002
0                   C7000   bay1  dpcfl1001.example.com  dpcfl1012.example.com
1                   C7000  bay10  dpcfl1010.example.com                   None
2                   C7000  bay11  dpcfl1011.example.com                   None
3                   C7000  bay12                inc1001                   None
4                   C7000  bay13                inc1003                   None
5                   C7000  bay14  dpcfl2313.example.com                   None
6                   C7000  bay15                lic1002                   None
7                   C7000   bay2  dpcfl1002.example.com  dpcfl1013.example.com
8                   C7000   bay3  dpcfl1003.example.com  dpcfl1014.example.com
9                   C7000   bay4  dpcfl1004.example.com  dpcfl1015.example.com
10                  C7000   bay5  dpcfl1005.example.com  dpcfl1016.example.com
11                  C7000   bay6  dpcfl1006.example.com  dpcfl1017.example.com
12                  C7000   bay7  dpcfl1007.example.com  dpcfl1018.example.com
13                  C7000   bay8  dpcfl1008.example.com                   None
14                  C7000   bay9  dpcfl1009.example.com                   None
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer +1,  there are four column names `Server` , `Enclosure Hardware`   , `Bay`     and    `Server Name`, i think we need to goupby  `Server` ?

Comment: See my edits. Hope I got the columns right. I printed the head for you to see. I am using df=pd.read_clipboard() and that can distort columns

Answer (score 1):

In dataframes, there are some relations between different values of different columns of the same row. So, I think using dataframes to obtain what you want isn't the best way to do it.

I suggest using a dictionary where the keys are `Server` and values are `Server Name` like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for name, group in df.groupby("Server"):
    dd[name] = group["Server Name"].values
```

Now, you can print all `Server Name` of a `Server` like so:

```
>>> dd["ENC1001"]
['dpcfl1001.example.com' 'dpcfl1002.example.com' 'dpcfl1003.example.com'
 'dpcfl1004.example.com' 'dpcfl1005.example.com' 'dpcfl1006.example.com'
 'dpcfl1007.example.com' 'dpcfl1008.example.com' 'dpcfl1009.example.com'
 'dpcfl1010.example.com' 'dpcfl1011.example.com' 'inc1001' 'inc1003'
 'dpcfl2313.example.com' 'lic1002']

>>> dd["ENC1002"]
['dpcfl1012.example.com' 'dpcfl1013.example.com' 'dpcfl1014.example.com'
 'dpcfl1015.example.com' 'dpcfl1016.example.com' 'dpcfl1017.example.com'
 'dpcfl1018.example.com']
```

And if you want to cast it into a `pandas.DataFrame`, you can simply run:

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd, orient='index').T
                  ENC1001                ENC1002
0   dpcfl1001.example.com  dpcfl1012.example.com
1   dpcfl1002.example.com  dpcfl1013.example.com
2   dpcfl1003.example.com  dpcfl1014.example.com
3   dpcfl1004.example.com  dpcfl1015.example.com
4   dpcfl1005.example.com  dpcfl1016.example.com
5   dpcfl1006.example.com  dpcfl1017.example.com
6   dpcfl1007.example.com  dpcfl1018.example.com
7   dpcfl1008.example.com                   None
8   dpcfl1009.example.com                   None
9   dpcfl1010.example.com                   None
10  dpcfl1011.example.com                   None
11                inc1001                   None
12                inc1003                   None
13  dpcfl2313.example.com                   None
14                lic1002                   None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anwarvic +1 , but i would like it all to be sorted itself rather selecting manually..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: i mean the format would be same as the desired output in the post.

Comment: I've edited my answer... hopefully this is what you meant :)