# How to Write a Cleaner and performant code with Pandas while reading CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a `CSV` data Sheet and want to parse and filter the data out it, While working on a code I found a similar code someone has asked on [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533780/pandas-convert-the-unique-column-value-as-a-column-name-and-place-all-relating-s) there and the author having almost the same H/W data as I see that related to HPE H/W where I have some data and columns are different.

### Sample Data:

```
Status  Server  Server Name Bay #   Model   Processor   Proc. Count Memory  Serial Number   State   Power State iLO FW  Firmware    Appliance Name
Critical    enc2010, bay 1  tdm2066.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101N9  Unmanaged   On  2.53 May 03 2017    I36 v2.40 (02/17/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  enc1011, bay 1  tdm1068.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101P6  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.74 (07/21/2019)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  enc1012, bay 1  tdm1083.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   262144  2M272101NX  Monitored   On  2.61 Jul 27 2018    I36 v2.60 (05/21/2018)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2004, bay 1  tdm2033.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262602L2  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2006, bay 1  vds2009 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M263604ZZ  Monitored   On  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.20 (05/05/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC2011, bay 1  tdm2081.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M2708027Z  Monitored   On  2.55 Aug 16 2017    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1003, bay 1  tdm1024.example.com 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262602KW  Monitored   On  2.73 Feb 11 2020    I36 v2.52 (10/25/2017)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1006, bay 1  vds1009 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M262505V5  Monitored   On  2.40 Dec 02 2015    I36 v2.00 (12/28/2015)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
OK  ENC1007, bay 1  vds1023 1   ProLiant BL460c Gen9    Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v4 @ 2.60GHz   2   524288  2M264800TR  Monitored   On  2.50 Sep 23 2016    I36 v2.30 (09/12/2016)  OV C7000 enclosures 1
```

### DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv("testcreate.csv", sep="\t")
df = df[[ 'Server', 'Server Name', 'Bay #',  'Appliance Name']]    
df['Bay'] = df['Server'].str.split(',').str[1].str.lower()
df['Enclosure'] = df['Server'].str.split(',').str[0].str.upper()
df['Server Name'] = df['Server Name'].str.split('.').str[0]
df = df.drop(['Server', 'Bay #'], axis=1)
df = df[df['Appliance Name'].str.contains('C7000')]
```

### Dataframe output:

```
   Server Name         Appliance Name     Bay Enclosure
0      tdm2066  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2010
1      tdm1068  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1011
2      tdm1083  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1012
3      tdm2033  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2004
4      vds2009  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2006
5      tdm2081  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2011
6      tdm1024  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1003
7      vds1009  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1006
8      vds1023  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1007
9      vds0003  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENT0003
10     tdm7123  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC7003
11     tdm2231  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2022
12     tdm2186  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2018
13     tdm1098  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1013
14     tdm1158  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1017
15     tdm2096  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2012
16     tdm1012  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1002
17     tdm1062  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1009
18     vds1041  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1010
19     vds1001  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1005
20     vds7025  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC7009
21     vds2023  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2007
22     tdm7068  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC7005
23     vds7006  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC7006
24     tdm2126  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2014
25     vds2001  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC2005
26     tdm1173  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1018
27     tdm1250  OV C7000 enclosures 1   bay 1   ENC1025
```

### What I tried:

I have borrowed the `df1 = pd.concat( [g.set_index('Bay').add_suffix(f'_{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Enclosure')], axis=1, sort=False).filter( like='Server Name').dropna(how='all', axis=1)` <-- this from the mentioned  SO post but i did not get it completely, also i do not want to add suffix ie `Server Name` hence it should be only `like`Enc1002` etc.

```
df1 = pd.concat( [g.set_index('Bay').add_suffix(f'_{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Enclosure')], axis=1, sort=False).filter( like='Server Name').dropna(how='all', axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Result:

[image]

### Desired:

```
        ENC1002 ENC1003 ENC1005
bay 1   tdm1012 tdm1024 vds1001
```

### EDIT:

I have got the Solution from @Scott for the `desired` solution.

```
df = pd.concat([g.set_index('Bay')['Server Name'].rename(f'{n}') for n, g in df.groupby('Enclosure')],  axis=1, sort=False)
```

My code may be a little messy which is shown under `Dataframe`, Is there a way to better code it, just asking it here to get better suggestions and code writings..

Comment: Do you have your sample data as it is or is it already part of a dataframe which is correctly formatted? Can you provide an example of the df.head(10). The reason I am asking is because I don't quite understand which part is what you're struggling with - to format the above text & put it into dataframe or if you have this already, to simply get to the desired output.

Comment: @DanailPetrov, Sample Data is Just a part of DataFrame  output of `df = pd.read_csv("testcreate.csv", sep="\t")`

Comment: This looks to be the same scenario almost which @Scott  answered in a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much scope in manipulation, after reading you post and code block. I would like to change it like below which will provide the desired result. However, I see a similar post on the code review.

1- You should pick and choose the desired columns which will reduce processing burden and little flexibility,  you can use `usecols` .

2- You can use `df.assign` along with Dict which will create a dict from two collections based on the `Keys, values` , this will create two distinct columns based on the `,` by splitting it, so you can do `split`, `rename` & `drop` action in one go.

It will go like below, which should work.

```
import pandas as pd
##### Pandas setting in case you want to visualize them on the screen. ####
#pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################### END OF THE Display Settings ###################
# usecols is supposed to provide a filter before reading the whole DataFrame
# into memory; if used properly, there should never be a need to delete columns
# after reading.
df = pd.read_csv("testcreate.csv",
                  usecols=['Server',
                           'Server Name',
                           'Appliance Name'
                          ]
                )
df1  = df.assign(**dict
              (zip
              ('xy',
              df.Server.str.split(',')
              .str
              )
              )
              ).rename(columns=
              {'x': 'Enclosure',
               'y': 'Bay'
              }
              ).drop(['Server'], axis=1)
df1 = df1[
          df1['Appliance Name']
          .str.contains('C7000')
         ]
df1['Server Name'] = df1['Server Name'].str.split('.').str[0].str.lower()

df1['Enclosure']  = df1['Enclosure'].str.upper()

df1 = pd.pivot(df1,
               values='Server Name',
               index='Bay',
               columns='Enclosure'
               ).rename_axis(None)

df1.to_csv("YourCsvFileName.csv")
# Print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got this correctly.

```
# Read the CSV & assign it to `text`
with open('estcreate.csv', 'r') as fh:
    text = fh.read()

enc = dict()

for line in text.splitlines()[1:]:
    status, enclosure, bay, bay_no, vds, *na = line.split()
    
    enclosure = enclosure.replace(',','').upper()
    vds = vds.lower().split('.')[0]
    
    if enclosure not in enc:
        enc[enclosure] = dict()
    if bay_no not in enc[enclosure]:
        enc[enclosure][bay_no] = vds
    
    
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(enc)
>>> df 

    ENC2010 ENC1011 ENC1012 ENC2004 ENC2006 ENC2011 ENC1003 ENC1006 ENC1007 ENT0003 ... ENC1010 ENC1005 ENC7009 ENC2007 ENC7005 ENC7006 ENC2014 ENC2005 ENC1018 ENC1025
1   tdm2066 tdm1068 tdm1083 tdm2033 vds2009 tdm2081 tdm1024 vds1009 vds1023 vds0003 ... vds1041 vds1001 vds7025 vds2023 tdm7068 vds7006 tdm2126 vds2001 tdm1173 tdm1250

>>> df.T
    1
ENC2010 tdm2066
ENC1011 tdm1068
ENC1012 tdm1083
ENC2004 tdm2033
ENC2006 vds2009
ENC2011 tdm2081
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Danail, but i need `Bay` as an Index as its shown in Result and  `Desired` , My whole code works but i need not to have Suffix  which you can see in the Suffix like `Server Name_Enc1001` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want to pivot your table:

```
df1 = pd.pivot(df, values='Server Name', index='Bay', columns='Enclosure')


Enclosure  ENC1003  ENC1006  ENC1007  ENC1011  ENC1012  ENC2004  ENC2006  ENC2010  ENC2011  ENT0003
Bay                                                                                                
bay 1      tdm1024  vds1009  vds1023  tdm1068  tdm1083  tdm2033  vds2009  tdm2066  tdm2081  vds0003
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and i knew the another trick, However, as you see `DataFrame` code which i think can be better formed as i am doing `split`, `rename` and multiple things which can be trimmed i think, that's i am looking for as well. +1

Comment: There isn't much you can do in text preprocessing. Each operation is different so you can't combine them. You can leave out dropping columns, it will save you a couple of lines. Also instead of  `df['Enclosure'] = df['Server'].str.split(',').str[0].str.upper()
` you can use `df['Enclosure'] = df['Server'].apply(lambda x: return x.split(',')[0].upper() )` but it's only style, and will not reduce line count.